# Access camel blueprint dataSource reference in java

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, apache-camel, datasource, javabeans

I defined a dataSource in a blueprint.xml which is deployed on karaf:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://server/db"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/mysqlDatasource" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

In my bundle inside the blueprint.xml I got the following reference and bean for this datasource:

```
<reference id="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"
    filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/mysqlDatasource)">
</reference>

<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

This way I can use the dataSource in my camel sql component.

Is it possible to get this datasource into any other java class inside this bundle?

```
<bean id="somebean" class="some.path.to.SomeClazz">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Because this obviously doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Why does it obvisously not work? blueprint can inject properties in bean as that last <bean> in your code.